# Difference static::class vs get_called_class() and __CLASS__ vs get_class() vs self::class

Tags: php, class, oop

I've seen several threads where people ask how to get the name of a class or an object in PHP. However, I can't see anywhere the difference between the various possibilities explained. I hope somebody here can help me.

So in order to get the class name of the called class, I know two possibilities:

1. `get_called_class()`
2. `static::class`

(`get_class($this)` for non-static classes)

And for getting the class name of the class in which you put the code, I know these three possibilities:

1. `get_class()`
2. `__CLASS__`
3. `self::class`

Are there any differences which I may to overlook right now? What are potential adventages and disadvantages of one way over the other?

Comment: Try to use all these methods in a class and in a class that extends it, in instance methods and in static methods to find out the answer.

Comment: That's what I did, and they all return the same result. I thought there might be some other difference I can't think of. After all, why did they introduce `::class` in PHP 5.5, when you could the same thing with `get_class()`, `__CLASS__` and `get_called_class()`?

Comment: `::class` can be evaluated at the compile time, `get_class()` is a function call, consequently the value it returns is available only on the execution time.

Comment: Does this mean `::class` is more efficient?

Comment: The difference is insignificant. If you aim for optimization then check the access to the database (optimize the SQL queries and reduce their number and the amount of data they retrieve), filesystem and remote resources.

Comment: @AlexanderJank: basically, `::class` was added to get the FQN of any class using just the local class name (no object, and from outside the class); that it can work like `get_class()`, `get_called_class()` and `__CLASS__` is just a knock-on effect. See the "[Class Name Resolution As Scalar Via "class" Keyword](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/class_name_scalars)" PHP RFC.

Answer (score 20):

**Differences between**

**[`get_class()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php)**

> returns the name of the class of an object

It returns a classname including its qualified namespace for the current class (without parameter) or for any specified object instance, when you pass the object instance pointer as the first and only parameter.

**[`__CLASS__`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)**

A magic constant that returns the qualified namespace and the current class name. Here you can not test for class names of other objects.
As per PHP 5.4 it works in traits. That is, when the trait is used in a class it will return the namespace and name of that class.

**[`::class`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.class.class)**

Only available since PHP 5.5. It uses class name and namespace resolution to obtain the info, as a result it does not need the class to be instantiated beforehand. Also note:

> The class name resolution using ::class is a compile time transformation. That means at the time the class name string is created no autoloading has happened yet. As a consequence, class names are expanded even if the class does not exist. No error is issued in that case.

**Tests**

```
<?php
namespace nTest;
trait tTest {
  function __toString() {return get_class();}
  function className() {return __CLASS__;}  // per PHP 5.4
  function traitName() {return __TRAIT__;}
}
class cTest {
  use tTest;
  function usedTraitName() {return __TRAIT__;}
}
class cClassWithoutObject {}
$oTest = new cTest;

header('Content-type: text/plain');
print                                  // Output:
    $oTest . PHP_EOL                   // 'nTest::cTest'
  . get_class($oTest) . PHP_EOL        // 'nTest::cTest'
  . $oTest->className() . PHP_EOL      // 'nTest::cTest'
  . $oTest->traitName() . PHP_EOL      // 'nTest::tTest' (trait!)
  . $oTest->usedTraitName() . PHP_EOL  // '' (no trait!)
  . cTest::class . PHP_EOL             // 'nTest::cTest'
  . cClassWithoutObject::class;        // 'nTest::cTestNotInstantiated'
```

Comment: I love you answer. Saved me from the burden of my curiosity!

Answer (score 8):

One difference between `__CLASS__` and `get_class($this)` that's important if you're using inheritance is that `__CLASS__` will give you the name of the class containing that code (which could be a parent class), whereas `get_class($this)` will give you the name of the concrete class of `$this` at runtime.

Example:

```
class Animal {

    function printCompileTimeType() {

        echo __CLASS__;
    }

    function printOverridableCompileTimeType() {

        echo __CLASS__;
    }

    function printType() {

        echo get_class($this);
    }
}

class Dog extends Animal {

    function printOverridableCompileTimeType() {

        echo __CLASS__;
    }
}

$animal = new Animal();
$dog = new Dog();

$animal->printCompileTimeType(); // Prints 'Animal'.
$animal->printOverridableCompileTimeType(); // Prints 'Animal'.
$animal->printType(); // Prints 'Animal'.

$dog->printCompileTimeType(); // Prints 'Animal'.
$dog->printOverridableCompileTimeType(); // Prints 'Dog'.
$dog->printType(); // Prints 'Dog'.
```

I'd say `get_class($this)` is generally more useful because it will work predictably no matter where you use it from, without needing to write repetitive override code like `printOverridableCompileTimeType`.